# Regex to match specific xml - section in Python

Tags: python, regex

I want to match the following markup

```
<text link="no">
    ...
</text>
```

The only thing important is that I want to match the text element with link="no" as an attribute and whatever is inside.

I'm using python and currently I have the following regex which is not working:

```
'<text [^<]*link="no"[^<]*>[.\t\n\r\xa0]*</text>[ \t\n\r\xa0]*'
```

So I'm considering that text could have other attributes.

Help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Why don't you use an XML parsing library?

Comment: It is a SO tradition to put this link here: **You can't parse [X]HTML with regex:** http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/471214

Comment: okay, so I guess I'll have to use a parsing lib....lets see what pyparsing has to offer...Thx for your responses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use  XML Parser (like [libxml2](http://xmlsoft.org/python.html) or [lxml](http://codespeak.net/lxml/) or [py-dom-xpath](http://code.google.com/p/py-dom-xpath/)) and XPath like:

```
//text[@link="no"]
```